# How do I monitor packets to and from a specific MAC on my LAN?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have a small LAN with a few Wifi IP cameras.  I want to monitor the number of packets sent to and from a specific Wifi IP camera.
I want to do this from another computer with a different LAN address.  Preferably I would like to see the number of packets sent and the time the activity occurs.  Is there software to do this?  Do I have to have this software or capability on the router?

Comment: Typically, this would done in a managed switch (hard-wired devices) or a WiFi Management Controller (wireles devices), not a router or computer. Monitoring a device by MAC address and counting and graphing/reporting the packet usage is an unusual request. Typically this type of reporting is reserved for enterprise class devices. What is the core issue you are trying to solve here with monitoring packet activity?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a network packet analyzer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Windump](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/)

Comment: This is a poor answer because it doesn't tell how this could be done (count and report usage by time frame) or the hardware changes involved. If you wish to answer a question, please be more specific. The OP's question wasn't about capturing packets, but counting them, and using this solution would require port mirroring and thus a managed switch (or a dumb hub) and would give the OP a full packet capture, not reporting data.

Comment: You are right. The answer is not very specific but neither was the question. I would have liked to comment on the OP's question but my reputation currently does not allow me to do that. So I answered the question "Is there software to do this?" in the hope to give more details after the OP get familiar with one of the tools...

Comment: Read here http://superuser.com/help about how to properly answer question and increase your reputation. Reputation has to be earned but it is not difficult if you follow the guild lines. The quickest way to gain enough reputation to comment is to become a member of another Stack Exchange group, an instant 100 rep. :)

Answer (score 1):

As for monitoring the traffic on your router, it depends on the device you are using for your router. If it is one the manufacturer markets to home or
[small office/home office (SOHO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_office/home_office) users, then it probably doesn't provide that capability unless you have replaced the firmware in the router with open source software that provides more capabilities than what is provided by the manufacturer, e.g., [OpenWRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenWrt), which is [Linux-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel). You could use a standard packet capture tool, [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump), if you are using OpenWRT - see [OpenWrt tcpdump packet captures for traffic evaluation](http://threatvectorsecurity.blogspot.com/2014/06/openwrt-tcpdump-packet-captures-for.html). You could replace your router or install another router in between the current one and the WiFi camera, if your current router doesn't provide that capability.

Alternatively, you could install [packet analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer), aka "sniffer", software on another system in the LAN. If you have a Linux system in the LAN, that system may already have [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump) on it; if not you should be able to easily install the utility using the package management system for your distribution of Linux. If you have an Apple [OS X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) system, it will have tcpdump on it, which you can run from a [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(OS_X)) window. For a Microsoft Windows system, you can install the equivalent [WinDump](https://www.winpcap.org/windump/), which is free. Like tcpdump it is a [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) utility.

A [graphical user interface (GUI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface) might be easier for you to use, if you are unfamiliar with network traffic capture and analysis, however. [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) is one of the most popular free tools that provides a GUI interface for traffic capture and analysis. You could install it on a Microsoft Windows, OS X, or Linux system. You can find online tutorials on its use, such as [How to Use Wireshark to Capture, Filter and Inspect Packets](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/) and even free online classes for Wireshark.

You can create a "filter" in the network analysis software such as tcpdump, windump, or Wireshark, to only capture network traffic to/from the MAC or IP address of the one IP camera you are interested in. E.g., see the answer to [TCPDump - Filter by MAC Address](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19737/tcpdump-filter-by-mac-address) at the [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) sister Stack Exchange site,

Keep in mind, though, that when you install the software on a particular device, you won't see all the traffic to/from the IP camera, just the traffic between the device on which you have installed the software and the WiFi camera.

For network analysis tools for Microsoft Windows systems, Nir Sofer also proivides the free [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) utility for Windows systems as well as many [other free network tools](http://www.nirsoft.net/network_tools.html).